# Question for using 8051(AT89S52) and CD4094BE

Tags: microcontroller

I want to use  AT89S52 connecting with CD4094BE  to control  8 LED  light bulbs.                                                 The program lanuage is ASM.
                                                                                                                                                        My aim is  the led lights up are as follow   :     1011 0011    ,1=off,  0= light up
[image]
The program are as follow :

```
       ORG 0000H

       AJMP MAIN


       MAIN: 

       SETB P1.4      ;STR 

       MOV A, #10110011           ;put the data into acc

       MOV P1.3 , A                    

       RRC A                            

       SETB P1.2                  ;CLK

       CLR P1.2                   ;CLK

       AJMP MAIN
```

what's wrong with my program/the schematic diagram  and how to correct it ?  Thank you.

Comment: It might help if you tell us what isn't working properly, and comment your program code with what you think each line does.

Comment: I don't see any current limiting resistors for the leds, have you used any?

Comment: Apart from the current limit resistors there are significant problems with the logic, you'll need a loop to clock in the data, the strobe will always be high and you'll possibly need extra delays depending on the clock rate of the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some possible mistakes:

> MOV P1.3, A

does not make sense to me, how are you moving 8 - bits, into a single bit? Maybe try writing 
MOV P1, A. At that point P1.3 should be the 4th bit of ACC.

> RRC A

This is not going to take effect the way you want, because each time the code loops at main, you are writing the same value back into A. Quick way of fixing this problem is by writing AJMP TEST instead of AJMP MAIN, at the end of your code, and placing TEST: label below the line:

> MOV A, #10110011

What is the clock speed of this micro-controller? If you do fix the RRC A problem you may see aliasing if its too fast, or it may appear that they are all on at the same time.